# Missing environment variables when using python's subprocess

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables

When I open a cmd in windows 10 and enter the `set` command I will normally get a list of all the environment variables on the system

(output was truncated due to irrelevent content only the path variable is conserved as it is the problematic one)

Output (cmd):

`Path=C:\smth;C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\ia32_win\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64_win\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP SDK\3.0\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\R3QU13M\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin`

Output using subprocess.call('set', shell=True))

```
Path=C:\Users\R3QU13M\Anaconda3\envs\StyleTransfer\Library\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\ia32_win\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64_win\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP SDK\3.0\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\R3QU13M\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin
```

My problem is that in the python's "subprocess call", the variable :

`C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16`

is missing. Is this a bug or am I missing something important?

Comment: Where is the missing key being defined?  If it's in the calling shell using `set`, I can't reproduce this on Python 2.7 or Python 3.6.

Comment: The Set command in windows is only used here to display the currently available environment variables

Comment: Your missing "variable" is not a variable. It is a string in the value of the `PATH` variable. You have provided insufficient information. In particular how the python program was run with respect to typing `set`. Did you run the python program from the same interactive session that you typed `set`?

Comment: The Windows shell (Explorer) is the original source of inherited environment variables, unless a process is started with a custom environment. Use Process Explorer to inspect the environment back up the process tree (i.e. cmd.exe child -> python.exe parent -> ...).

Comment: @eryksun Thank you I might figure it out with that